# Displaying DIV inside a Canvas clipping path

Tags: html, canvas

I have a DIV container that I want to place inside a Canvas element, how do I set the clipping path of the #canvasContents to the Canvas shape?

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="400"></canvas>

<div id="canvasContents" width="500" height="400">canvas contents</div>

<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var x = 120, y = 70;
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(x, y);
context.bezierCurveTo(x, y, x + 6, y - 82, x + 98, y - 25);
context.bezierCurveTo(x + 210, y - 5, x + 325, y + 2, x + 283, y + 78);
context.bezierCurveTo(x + 244, y + 173, x + 237, y + 270, x + 138, y + 235);
context.bezierCurveTo(x - 29, y + 185, x - 145, y + 154, x - 65, y + 99);
context.closePath();
context.lineWidth = 1;
context.fillStyle = '#FFF';
context.fill();
context.strokeStyle = '#000';
context.stroke();
</script>
```

Comment: The only way you can see elements which are placed inside of the canvas element is when the canvas element isn't supported by the browser.

Answer (score 2):

You can't place anything inside a canvas element. The content inside a canvas element will only show if canvas is not supported in a browser. In other cases it's ignored.

You can try to use SVG to place a div inside by wrapping the code inlined for the SVG but there are some restrictions related to external content.

You need to build an inline SVG like this:

```
var inlineSVG =
   '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50">' +
   '<foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">' +

   ourHTMLgoesHere +

   '</foreignObject></svg>';
```

Then convert it to blob and url:

```
var svg = new Blob([inlineSVG], {type:"image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"});
var url = URL.createObjectURL(svg);
```

Now you can set this as an image source, load it and then draw it to canvas.

For simplicity I made this function to do all the hard work (please see link above for details). Text can be any HTML including the div you need to wrap inside. Just remember it cannot contain links to external content (images, css, fonts etc.):

```
/**
 *    Canvas extension: drawHTMLText(txt, options)
 *    By Ken Fyrstenberg, Epistemex
 *    http://epistemex.com/
 *
 *    USAGE:
 *        myContext.drawHTMLText(txt [, options]);
 *
 *    var options = {x: startPosition,
 *                   y: startPosition,
 *                   width: maxWidth,
 *                   height: maxHeight,
 *                   callback: myFunction,
 *                   callbackError: myErrorFunction}
 *
 *    Each individual option is optional in themself. The callback
 *    on success contains an object with reference to result and
 *    originalText. Error callback is provided with the error object.
 *
 *    License: MIT
 */
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.drawHTMLText = function(txt, options) {

    /// make sure we have an object if none was provided
    options = options || {};

    var ctx = this,

        /// build inline SVG
        iSVG =

        '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="' +
        (options.width ? options.width : ctx.canvas.width) +

        '" height="' +
        (options.height ? options.height : ctx.canvas.height) +
        '"><foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">' +

        '<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="font:' +
        ctx.font + ';color:' + ctx.fillStyle + '">' +

        txt +

        "</div></foreignObject></svg>",

        /// create Blob of inlined SVG
        svg = new Blob([iSVG],{type:"image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"}),

        /// create URL (handle prefixed version)
        domURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self,
        url = domURL.createObjectURL(svg),

        /// create Image
        img = new Image;

    /// handle image loading
    img.onload = function () {

        /// draw SVG to canvas
        ctx.drawImage(img,
                      (options.x ? options.x : 0),
                      (options.y ? options.y : 0));

        domURL.revokeObjectURL(url);

        /// invoke callback if provided
        if (typeof options.callback === 'function')
            options.callback({result: img,
                              originalText: txt});
    };

    /// handle potential errors
    img.onerror = function(e) {
        if (typeof options.callbackError === 'function') {
            options.callbackError(e);
        } else {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }

    img.src = url;
}
```

If you need clipping just add that to the canvas itself using `context.clip()` after defining a path.

Comment: +1 Nice answer, definitely thinking out of the box :)

Comment: @Loktar yeah, it's pretty nifty what the svg can do on the canvas. I wrote that function originally to just (automagically) wrap text on the canvas, but it's so much more powerful than that.

Answer (score 0):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/6znHS/1/)**

Here is one way to accomplish it, first I put the canvas element over the div just using absolute positioning like so

```
canvas {
    position:absolute
}
#canvasContents {
    position:absolute;
    background:blue;
    width:500px;
    height:400px;
    line-height:400px;
    text-align:center
}
```

Then I fill the canvas and use clipping to show the effect.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var x = 120,
    y = 70;
context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

context.save();
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(x, y);
context.bezierCurveTo(x, y, x + 6, y - 82, x + 98, y - 25);
context.bezierCurveTo(x + 210, y - 5, x + 325, y + 2, x + 283, y + 78);
context.bezierCurveTo(x + 244, y + 173, x + 237, y + 270, x + 138, y + 235);
context.bezierCurveTo(x - 29, y + 185, x - 145, y + 154, x - 65, y + 99);
context.closePath();
context.clip();
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.restore();
```

The key with clipping is to save the context, draw your path, and then call clip. After that you can do a fill, or in this example a `clearRect` which will show whatever is positioned behind the canvas element.

Comment: The DIV container needs to go inside the Canvas, not behind it.

Comment: @PaulGeronca An element cannot be placed inside the canvas element and shown. The only way you will see the element placed inside a canvas element is if the browser doesn't support canvas (IE8 and below). Your best bet is to place the canvas element in front of any you want to show.